# Please is polite but can adding it seem impolite or impatient

Tags: grammar, politeness, business-language

Example:

I send my boss or co-worked the following message without please:

> I need my [some specific company] software updated.

In an effort to be polite, I'll add please:

> I need my [some specific company] software updated, please.

To me, this can come off as actually being less polite and or impatient.
Does anyone agree?

Take 3:

> I need my [some specific company] software updated, please.  Thanks!

I add the thanks on at the end (early) as a way to 'soften' it.
Is that better?

Comment: I might add that the reason for asking my boss is not that the boss has to do menial labor, but in our organization must approve everything.  Hence, it  is more efficient if the boss sends the request than if I do, and not much extra work for the boss, either.

Comment: "Could you authorise an update of my X software, please?"

Comment: Agree with @KateBunting's phrasing (would personally put the please after "you")... the absence of "please" is less the issue than making a request in the form of "I need..."  Remember what happens in A Few Good Men when Kaffee says "I'll just need a copy of Santiago's transfer order."

Comment: It seems to me to depend on how badly it is needed, and to what extent your request is already anticipated. You don't always have to use the word "please". As long as the request is politely structured, you can manage without the word.  "I am wondering if there might be any chance of getting my software updated." "Could you be so kind as to approve the software update that we discussed, please?" Would there be any chance of getting the software update approved before month end, do you think? The important thing is that it be written as a courteous request and not as a demand.

Comment: This is a better fit with the Interpersonal Skills.SE template.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It is also about how to write well.

Comment: @WS2 One tries to allocate to the most relevant site. Hedging has been addressed on ELU; I remember the triply hedged (or quadruply if you count the _?_ where modern conventions allow it to be omitted with polite requests). "Could you please just pass the salt?" But all such polite forms depend on delivery, which is really beyond our remit.

Comment: I think it all depends on 'intonation'; it can make 'please' displeasing.  While writing, it's a problem when the audience is unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boss's name], I'm unable to complete [relevant business task] as I am currently on [the particular version] of [the software].

If you could please direct me as to how I could get version [X] installed I would very much appreciate the help.

-[you]

When dealing w/superiors it is best to lead with the business reason behind your ask. You're not asking because you want your boss to do menial labor, you are asking because you are part of their business unit and you don't want to miss deadlines.

The "please" in the above is for your boss to teach you how to get software upgraded. There is an implication that you'll be taking this over from now on b/c you will know how. Bosses tend to like this.

Source: am boss.

Comment: Please see comment on my original  post.  NOTE:  I accepted this as answer, but that's probably too much in my organization as much of that is just assumed.  People like to keep emails rather limited.  However, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of a general phenomenon of words/constructions that are normally used to convey politeness producing the opposite effect, sometimes intentionally, sometimes unintentionally.

To understand why this is so, we need to note that the level of politeness that is appropriate to a particular interaction depends on the circumstances: the nature of the setting, one's relationship with the person one is speaking to, whether any third parties are present, how usual or unusual the interaction is, and so forth. Other things being equal, addressing a stranger calls for a higher level of politeness than speaking to somebody with whom one has an established relationship, and asking for a favour calls for being more polite than making a routine, everyday request.

The level of politeness may thus carry conversational implicatures. Using a relatively high level of politeness may convey that one perceives the person one is speaking to as a relative stranger, and that may be hurtful if the person thought that you were friends, or even just friendly colleagues. Similarly, using a high level of politeness in making a routine, everyday request may convey the idea that the other person perhaps does not understand that the matter is routine and may thus convey a mild rebuke for the matter not having been already attended to.

Whether these considerations actually apply to the specific scenario that the OP describes depends on the details; so far as what is given in the question is concerned, the only thing that can be said is that the pragmatics of politeness is such that they might apply.

Answer (score 1):

I think, perhaps, the 'thanks' is a bit much, but not the 'please.' 'Thanks' makes the request sound like an order, giving your request the air of 'get it done asap' rather than 'thank you so much for considering.' If you *must* include a thanks, spell it all out and say 'thank you.'

As far as 'please' coming off as rude: I can't think of a single person that's ever been offended by a little bit of politeness. I think you might be reading too far into things, but I could be wrong; it's all a matter of what your company culture is like and whether such an innocuous phrase could be seen as a micro-agression.

Best of luck!

Comment: I already accepted answer above, but this is a good one too.  It is more fitting to my own situation, so thanks!  (Thank you)